# How do you get a working interaction with ConfigureAwait(true) in a console application?

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronization

In a small project i am working on i have the neccessity for a component to execute a components shutdown code in the same thread that it was initialized in. However unlike in WPF/Winforms/Web the synchronizationcontext which takes care of this does not work.

My guess is that the lack of a synchronization context is the issue that causes the lack of utilization for ConfigureAwait(true).

Does someone know how to properly implement this?

I read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) article but could not make any sense of it yet. Perhaps it was too late yesterday.

Minimal Repro:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleSyncContext
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await SomeBackgroundWorkAsync();
            // if this is the same thread as above the question is solved.
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        private static async Task SomeBackgroundWorkAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*i have the neccessity for a component to execute a components shutdown code in the same thread that it was initialized in*" - explain why you need this ? Also define component in your words

Comment: The component throws an exception otherwise

Comment: Just for my information, what sort of component is this?

Comment: CefSharp.OffScreen

Comment: Can you paste this into the question, also can you paste the exact exception you are getting

Comment: `MultiThreadedMessageLoop` it sounds like you want to set this to true, or potentially some other option. (just a guess)

Comment: You need to post minimal failing example, otherwise it's hard to give an advice on how to fix.

Comment: sample added to question

Answer (score 3):

As you already figured out, console application by default doesn't have synchronization context, so `ConfigureAwait` has no effect, and continuation after your `await SomePageLoad()` will run on random thread pool thread. Note that using async main method is essentially equivalent to this:

```
static async Task AsyncMain() { ... } // your `async Task Main method`

// real Main method generated by compiler
static void RealMain() {
    AsyncMain().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
}
```

In your case you don't need any synchronization context though. What you want is initialize CefSharp on main thread and shutdown CefSharp on main thread. So instead of using async Main - you can do the same as above, but initialize and shutdown Cef outside of async method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // starting with thread 1
    Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
    try {
        AsyncMain(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    finally {
        // we are on main thread here
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }

}

static async Task AsyncMain(string[] args) {
    await SomePageLoad(); // more stuff here
}
```

Edit: if you insist on using synchronization context then it can be done, but will add a lot of complications for nothing. Out goal is create synchronization context which will run all actions on the same thread. This case be done with simple actions queue, here is basic implementation (don't use it in production, provided as an example only, no exception handling and so on):

```
class CustomSyncContext : SynchronizationContext {
    private readonly BlockingCollection<WorkItem> _queue = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>(new ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem>());
    private readonly Thread _thread;
    public CustomSyncContext() {
        // start new thread which will handle all callbacks
        _thread = new Thread(() => {
            // set outselves as current sync context for this thread
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this);
            foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
                try {
                    // execute action
                    item.Action();
                }
                finally {
                    // if this action is synchronous, signal the caller
                    item.Signal?.Set();
                }
            }
        });
        _thread.Start();
    }
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        // Post means acion is asynchronous, just queue and forget
        _queue.Add(new WorkItem(() => d(state), null));
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        // Send means action is synchronous, wait on a single until our thread executes it
        using (var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false)) {
            _queue.Add(new WorkItem(() => d(state), signal));
            signal.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    public void Shutdown() {
        // signal thread that no more callbacks are expected
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public void WaitForShutdown() {
        _thread.Join();
    }

    private class WorkItem {
        public WorkItem(Action action, ManualResetEvent signal) {
            Action = action;
            Signal = signal;
        }
        public Action Action { get; }
        public ManualResetEvent Signal { get; }
    }
}
```

And your code then becomes:

```
var ctx = new CustomSyncContext();
ctx.Send(async (_) => {
    try {
        // starting with thread 1
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());

        // this method returns on thread 4
        await SomePageLoad();
    }
    finally {
        Cef.Shutdown();
        // signal the context we are done, so that main thread can unblock
        ctx.Shutdown();
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}, null);

ctx.WaitForShutdown();
```

Now your code runs on custom synchronization context, and continuation after `await SomePageLoad();` will be posted to that synchronization context and executed by our thread (the same thread which inited CefSharp) (no `ConfigureAwait(true)` is needed, as it's already true by default). Note that we achieved nothing useful - we have one more thread, and our main thread is still blocked waiting for the whole operation to complete (there is no sensible way around that).

Edit 2: here is variation which does not require separate thread, but is not much better:

```
class CustomSyncContext : SynchronizationContext {
    private readonly BlockingCollection<WorkItem> _queue = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>(new ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem>());
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        // Post means acion is asynchronous, just queue and forget
        _queue.Add(new WorkItem(() => d(state), null));
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        // Send means action is synchronous, wait on a single until our thread executes it
        using (var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false)) {
            _queue.Add(new WorkItem(() => d(state), signal));
            signal.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    public void Shutdown() {
        // signal thread that no more callbacks are expected
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public void Start() {
        // now we run the loop on main thread
        foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
            try {
                // execute action
                item.Action();
            }
            finally {
                // if this action is synchronous, signal the caller
                item.Signal?.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    private class WorkItem {
        public WorkItem(Action action, ManualResetEvent signal) {
            Action = action;
            Signal = signal;
        }
        public Action Action { get; }
        public ManualResetEvent Signal { get; }
    }
}

static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    var ctx = new CustomSyncContext();
    // set sync context
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctx);
    // now execute our async stuff
    var task = DoStuff().ContinueWith(x => ctx.Shutdown());
    // now run the loop of sync context on the main thread.
    // but, how do we know when to stop? Something from outside should singal that
    // in the case signal is completion of DoStuff task
    // note that most of the time main thread is still blocked while waiting for items in queue
    ctx.Start();
}

private static async Task DoStuff() {
    try {
        // starting with thread 1
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());

        // this method returns on thread 4
        await SomePageLoad();
    }
    finally {
        Cef.Shutdown();
        // signal the context we are done, so that main thread can unblock
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work yes, but i don't want to block for the sake of getting my code to work. I was aware i could do it like this before posting the question here. I was more interested in learning how to properly solve this with a synchronization context in an environment where there is no prebuilt synchronization context, by someone who ran into this issue before i did. I read many of Stephen Clearys blog articles, but this topic i did not run into before.

Comment: @Dbl but you already do the same with your `async Main` method, as I described in answer. You cannot "avoid blocking" in console application, because main application thread cannot exit until you are done with process. So main thread should do something while your async calls are in progress, usually that something is blocking. Doing it the way described in answer is exactly the same as you are doing it now, except shutdown runs on the same thread.

Comment: So to clarify - this is not a "hack" or anything, it's a proper way to do what you want to.

Comment: I know. I am aware that this is no hack and works just fine. I am just curious how this works without blocking async calls using a synchronization context. When i asked this question i was already aware of how to solve my issue without a synchronization context. This question is designated to specifically solving it in a way where ConfigureAwait does what it is meant to do.

Comment: @Dbl I've added sample implementation of sync context and my comments about that.

Comment: Also added a variation without separate thread in second edit

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is indeed the lack of a Synchronisation context. You can't use `ConfigureAwait(true)` as this implies that you need to return to the original `scheduler/context` which does not exist.

#### Custom implementation

A very simple implementation that ought to do the trick is the one found [here](https://veganhunter.net/2016/12/02/synchronizationcontext-in-console-applications/). Basically two steps.

1. Implement a custom synchronization context

```
public class CustomSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback action, object state)
    {
        SendOrPostCallback actionWrap = (object state2) =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new CustomSynchronizationContext());
            action.Invoke(state2);
        };
        var callback = new WaitCallback(actionWrap.Invoke);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, state);
    }
    public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
    {
        return new CustomSynchronizationContext();
    }
    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        base.Send(d, state);
    }
    public override void OperationStarted()
    {
        base.OperationStarted();
    }
    public override void OperationCompleted()
    {
        base.OperationCompleted();
    }
}
```

2. Initaliaze it and use it

```
static void Main()
    {
        var context = new CustomSynchronizationContext();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
```

#### AsyncEx library

You can also use the [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(() => AsyncMethod(args));
    }
 
    static async void AsyncMethod(string[] args)
    {
        await something().ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
```

Comment: Though this will likely work,  my gut feeling is this should not be needed

Comment: Agreed, but not having any example, I just try to answer the question at hand in the hopes that it will help someone that truly needs it.

Comment: Hm. Does not return on the the same thread. I will add some short repro code

Comment: Code added. Thanks for sharing the implementation though. It looked like it would work for me too, perhaps something small is missing

Comment: This custom implementation cannot work for OP's use case, because in Post your explicitly call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, so continuation will execute on thread pool thread, the same as without synchronization context at all.

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea to call `SetSynchronizationContext` on `ThreadPool` threads. These threads are intended to be contextless.

Comment: Neither I think that it's a good idea to pass an `async void` lambda as an argument of the [`AsyncContext.Run`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext) method. This method understands async delegates (`async Task`) just fine.